# Automatically change the powerbi report publish changing data source

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-automate

I have .Pbix file with me for a powerBI report and i need to use that as atemplate for many workspaces. I tryied to do it with power automate but the thing is it is published with the data source saved in the .pbix file.I need to update thea data source only in the template and use it in many workspaces with different datasets but in same structure.

I was expected to update only the dataset and it is creating new report

[i added the image to understand what i need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yhyr.png)

as of now I'm updating every workspace manually when i did a change to report template i need to automate this process.

Comment: What kind of data sources is your PBIX using? Have you looked into .PBIT Power BI Template, where it saves the report without the data. And if you use parameters for your data source, it will ask you for them when you open it up the .PBIT

Comment: I'm using synapse serverless sql pool and i added diagram to the question to get a better understanding. @SamNseir

Comment: Thanks, and are you looking to deploy / publish these to the workspaces programmatically? Or will end users do this themselves for their Workspace?

Comment: Yes I'm looking to deploy /publish it to their workspaces which i already have access and the workspaces are in the same tenant. not only that I'm using synapse to refresh the dataset per day for every workspace. only place I've stuck is there are no way i found to update the dataset without changing the template. In the powerBI api also don't have an API to publish with changing the data source. But I found a way to publish pbix file using API following  this refferece: https://joelleichty.com/2022/09/25/use-power-automate-http-connector-to-publish-pbix-file-using-the-power-bi-api/ @SamNseir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Power BI REST APIs. You can update data sources of datasets (and much more).
See [Datasets - Update Datasources In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/update-datasources-in-group)

Comment: But it is not supported for the data source type which I'm using.

Comment: As per the Limitations in the link provided: "Only these data sources are supported: SQL Server, Azure SQL Server, Azure Analysis Services, Azure Synapse, OData, SharePoint, Teradata, and SAP HANA. For other data sources, use the Update Parameters In Group API call.
Changing the data source type isn't supported." Which data source type are you using? If it isn't supported, the you can work around it by using Parameters. Then via the API you can update the parameter per workspace.